# How to vary impulse/velocity based on screen size/device

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I am building a game with swift where I have sprites moving around the screen that you have to avoid. When I test the game on say iphone 5, the objects are harder to avoid than on the 6 or 6+. I think this is because I had the velocity the same across the board (I am adjusting the sizes based on screen size). I changed the original impulse to try and vary based on the screen size with matching the numbers I originally had for the CGVectors with this

```
let gOneX = screenWidth/6
let gOneY = screenHeight/9
let gTwoX = screenWidth/6
let gTwoY = screenHeight/9

ghostOne.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVectorMake(gOneX, -gOneY))
ghostTwo.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVectorMake(-gTwoX, gTwoY))
```

I did this, and it helped enough to notice a difference between devices, but it was still not acceptable. The objects were still harder or easier to avoid based on device.

Is there any other way I can vary the impulse?

Comment: Sure. Set your own manual values based on screen size.

Comment: How would I do that? If statements?

Comment: IF statements will work fine.

Comment: How can I find out what device they are on?

Comment: Each device has a screen width/height. There are also other ways. Google something like iOS determine which device or similar.